# When I copy a user in Active Directory it doesn't copy the street address

Tags: powershell

So I'm trying to use PowerShell and a CSV file to populate users street address as well as city, state, zip, etc (in case they move to a new office location their street, city, state, zip will be updated appropriately).  Obviously, my OUs are structured by location.  My CSV file has 5 columns (Street, Street2, City, State, Zip).  Street2 is the suite typically that I want on another line.  Although if the zip starts with a zero it gets lost but that's another subject.

Everything works up to line 9 (`Get-ADUser`) then starting line 10 (`Set-ADUser`) it fails and I think I know why I just haven't figured out how to get past it.  I can't use `$_` for two different values in the `for-eachobject` loop 
 for `Get-ADUser` and `Set-ADUser`.

```
Import-CSV .\Offices.csv |

ForEach-Object {
        if($_.Office -eq "Office1"){
            $OUStr = "OU=Office1,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=local"
            }elseif($_.Office -eq "Office2"){
            $OUStr = "OU=Office2,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=local"
            }
        Get-ADUser -Filter "L -eq `"$($_.Office)`"" -SearchBase "$OUStr" -Properties streetAddress,L,st,postalCode |

Set-ADUser -Replace @{
        streetAddress="$_.Street" + "`r`n" + "$_.Street2"
        L="$_.City"
        st="$_.State"
        postalCode="$_.Zip"
        }
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: The $_ in your set-aduser statement comes from each object generated from the get-aduser command. There is no AD attribute called street2 unless you changed your ad schema to include it. You could create variables earlier in your foreach loop that contain the CSV properties, so that you don’t need to reference those as $_ in your set-aduser command.

Comment: That might be the best way to go as long as I can pull those variables and update them as the script goes along in the `Get-ADUser` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is perhaps easier if you define a hashtable to store all the attributes you want to update and use that for the `Set-ADUser` cmdlet.

**Using -Replace with LDAP attribute names**

```
$CSV = Import-CSV .\Offices.csv 

foreach ($user in $CSV) {
    switch ($user.Office) {
        "Office1" { $OUStr = "OU=Office1,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=local"; break }
        "Office2" { $OUStr = "OU=Office2,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=local"; break }
    }
    # With –Replace you're using the LDAP names of the properties rather than the PowerShell name.
    $attribs = @{
        streetAddress = "{0}`r`n{1}" -f $user.Street, $user.Street2
        l             = $user.City
        st            = $user.State
        postalCode    = $user.Zip
    }

    Get-ADUser -Filter "City -eq '$($user.Office)'" -SearchBase $OUStr |
    Set-ADUser -Replace $attribs
}
```

**Splatting the parameters using the PowerShell or GUI attribute names**

```
$CSV = Import-CSV .\Offices.csv 

foreach ($user in $CSV) {
    switch ($user.Office) {
        "Office1" { $OUStr = "OU=Office1,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=local"; break }
        "Office2" { $OUStr = "OU=Office2,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=local"; break }
    }
    # With splatting you use the PowerShell or GUI names of the properties.
    $attribs = @{
        StreetAddress = "{0}`r`n{1}" -f $user.Street, $user.Street2
        City          = $user.City
        State         = $user.State
        PostalCode    = $user.Zip
    }

    Get-ADUser -Filter "City -eq '$($user.Office)'" -SearchBase $OUStr |
    Set-ADUser @attribs
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That works great, I tested the first (Replace) but didn't test the Splatting but I'm sure it works too.

Now they switched things up on me.  They want the corporate office broken out into sub groups like Finance, HR, etc.  I should be able to do an IF statement in the SWITCH section to select the attributes in the CSV file...should be interesting.

Comment: Correction...I can't do the IF statement but I can add an office location for the departments in the CSV file and that would work best.  Thanks @Theo and AdminOfThings

Comment: Wow, it worked great until they split out the Corporate office with their own OUs.  I will have to try AdminOfThings selection below so I can do the `IF` selections.

Comment: @Jas If I understand correctly, you can simply add more expressions to the switch resulting in more OUs. Usually that leads to cleaner code than a bunch of `if...elseif...else` tests.

Comment: yeah I thought of that too but it's inconsistent.  It works on some OUs but not all OUs.  Not even cronologically, it will skip one or two or three OUs without updating but then on the fourth it will update the users.  I double checked the spelling of each OU, the office address of each entry in the CSV file but I've never seen it randomly pick which ones it wants to update.  I have seen ISE go weird on me before and I have to close it all out and open again and it works fine but not this time.  Only thing working consistently is eliminating the CSV file and putting the address in script

Comment: @Jas Since the situation changed on you, I suggest you post a new question. Take care to include some of your (sanitized) input CSV and give us an idea of how the OUs are nested now (or not). At this point I do not have enough information on the structure in your organization to be able to edit the code accordingly..

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
Import-CSV .\Offices.csv |

ForEach-Object {
        if($_.Office -eq "Office1"){
            $OUStr = "OU=Office1,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=local"
            }elseif($_.Office -eq "Office2"){
            $OUStr = "OU=Office2,OU=User Accounts,DC=domain,DC=local"
        }
        $streetAddress = $_.street + "`r`n" + $_.street2
        $City = $_.City
        $state = $_.State
        $postalCode = $_.zip
        Get-ADUser -Filter "L -eq `"$($_.Office)`"" -SearchBase "$OUStr" -Properties streetAddress,L,st,postalCode | 
        Set-ADUser -Replace @{
            streetAddress=$streetAddress
            L=$City
            st=$state
            postalCode=$postalCode
            }
}
```

I am setting variables for everything you need in the replace hashtable before the Get-Aduser command. This will allow you to reference the object passed into the `ForEach` loop.

Comment: Tried this one too and its random on which ones it updates just like I'm seeing in the above script now.  Great solution but I may have to eliminate the CSV file which I don't want to do but I guess I will.  They won't move office locations much anyway so might was well make it easy.  Thanks AdminOfThings!